# Permission denied to create files on Samba shared folder mounted using CIFS

Tags: permissions, samba, lubuntu

I have two ubuntu (lubuntu 20.10) machines. On one of the machines, I created a folder and shared it using samba.

My entry in /etc/samba/smb.conf looks like this

```
[MyShare]
  comment = NO COMMENTS
  path = /home/user1/Documents/Shared
  read only = no
  guest ok = yes
  writeable = yes
```

For the folder `/home/user1/Documents/Shared` I have set permissions to `777`.

From the second machine, I mounted the shared folder using cifs, using the below command

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o rw,guest,vers=2.0 //user1-pc.local/myshare /media/share
```

(user1-pc is the hostname of the first machine.)

Now, I am able to `cd` into `/media/share`, view contents of files using `cat` command. However, I am unable to create new files using `touch` command.

The command I used was, `touch first.txt`
The error was, `touch: cannot touch 'first.txt': Permission denied`

I am new to working with permissions in linux. Kindly help me with overcoming the issue.

Comment: It's not any permission related? (I mean, locally or remotely,  the file is not in a directory which only root (for example) has access to? (note: not in the local,  I see you are running with sudo) but,  another thing,  do you think it could be the version? (e.g  tried  vers=3.0 instead of 2.0?) (if there is 3.0, if not - try 3)

Comment: Can you try specifying a guest account? The manpage for smb.conf says that the `guest ok = yes` option allows clients to connect without a password and with the privileges of the guest account. The default guest account is the 'nobody' user, which might explain the limited access. Link: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#GUESTACCOUNT

Comment: Sorry for my limited knowledge on UNIX: In that case, should I increase privileges of 'nobody' user?

Comment: @Kannan No, the preferred approach would be create a dedicated user account for this purpose, give it the appropriate permissions on the shared path as per your requirement, and then modify your Samba config to use that account.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will do that. If you can post the same as answer I will mark as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

For all the people that didn't read the coments on the original post, [Haxiel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/173368/haxiel) said:

The [man page for smb.conf](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html) says that the `guest ok = yes` option allows clients to connect without a password and with the privileges of the guest account. The default guest account is the 'nobody' user.

The preferred approach in this case would be to create a dedicated user account for this purpose, give it the appropriate permissions on the shared path as per your requirement, and then modify your Samba config to use that account. (Syntax: `guest account = ftp`).

Comment: Hi, thanks for writing this up. I've added some details and modified them a little so that this reads as a proper answer.

Comment: No problem, i will need to learn to make better awnsers...